# How to specify documentclass option for a 5 inch * 7 inch book?

Tags: formatting

I wanted to use Latex to make a book. But not in A4 size. I want it in
5 inch * 7 inch. The standard size for a novel.

In `\documentclass[a4paper]{book}`, is there anything that can replace
'a4paper' which will help me to achieve this? Or will I have to
manually set all the margins and spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}     
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7in]{geometry} 
...
```

other margins can also be set by that package. See documentation.

Comment: Do I need to specify it as "article" for this? Won't "book" do?

Comment: sure, if you need chapters.